# Getting json formatted obejct from the database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a simple php code which retrieves data from database and displays in json format as below

```
[

{
S.no: "1",

News: "http://bbau.ac.in/Office%20Notice/off%20note/Aug15/1766.pdf",

Date: "2015-08-11",

news_desc: "Minute to Minute Programme on 15th August"

},

{
S.no: "2",

News: "http://bbau.ac.in/Office%20Notice/off%20note/Aug15/1760.pdf",

Date: "2015-08-11",

news_desc: "Sub - committee to look into the all sign boards of the buildings"

}

]
```

But I want this result in an array so that my json output should be as

```
News:[

  {
S.no: "1",

News: "http://bbau.ac.in/Office%20Notice/off%20note/Aug15/1766.pdf",

Date: "2015-08-11",

news_desc: "Minute to Minute Programme on 15th August"

},

{

S.no: "2",

News: "http://bbau.ac.in/Office%20Notice/off%20note/Aug15/1760.pdf",

Date: "2015-08-11",

news_desc: "Sub - committee to look into the all sign boards of the buildings"

}

]
```

I am pasting the php code below:

```
 <?php

$con=$con=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect'.mysql_error());
    }
mysql_select_db("mysql",$con);
$result=mysql_query("Select * from bbau_news");
$array=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $output[]=$row;
    }
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Please help as I am new to JSON and PHP

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
$output[]=$row;
```

To

```
$output['News'][]=$row;
```

This should give the output you want.

Answer (score 2):

Change from

```
print(json_encode($output));
```

To

```
print(json_encode(array('News', $output)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$output['News']=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $output['News'][]=$row;
    }
```

Try this. It will work.

Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to first json_decode the JSON from DB

```
$jsonArray = json_decode( $row['json'], true );  //true will give array else it will give object
```

Then

```
$output[] = json_encode( array( 'News', $jsonArray ) );
```

Then $output will have the the format that you need.